# I am trying to read a .txt file and create two new lists out of it. In python

Tags: python, list, indexing

I am a beginner. I have been asked to help my niece with an assignment for school. 
She had sample code to write but had to put it in order. Also was given a .txt file to use.

I will post the code.

```
def FileRead(FileName):

    Data = ""

    DesLine = ""

    FileContents = []

    try:
        Fpl = open(FileName,'r')
        DesLine = Fpl.readline()

        Data = Fpl.read()

    except IOError:
        print("Error unable to read file or does not exist")
        print("Exiting the programme")
        stop = input()
        Fpl.close()
        sys.exit(1)

    ListSeq = Data.split('\n')

    DnaSeq = ('').join(ListSeq)

    FileContents.append(DesLine)
    FileContents.append(DnaSeq)

    return FileContents
```

## ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
def main():


    FileContents = []

    DnaSeq = ''

    FileName = input("Enter file name: ")

    Filecontents = FileRead(FileName)

    DesLine = FileContents[0]

    DnaSeq = FileContents[1]

    print("The Contents of {:s} are : \n".format(FileContents))
    print(FileContents[0])
    print(FileContents[1])
```

## -------------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
def Translate(DnaSequence, RFNumber):

    AminoAcidList = []
    AminoAcidSeq = ''

    DnaSequenceRF = DnaSequence[RFNumber:len(DnaSequence)]

    print("\n\nThe DNA sequence for Readin Frame {:} is: \n".format(RFNumber+1))
    print(DnaSequnceRF)


    for n in range(RFNumber,len(DnaSequence),3):

        codon = DnaSequence[n:n+3]

        if codon in CodonTable:
            AminoAcid = CodonTable[codon]
            AminoAcidSeq += AminoAcid
    return AminoAcidSeq
```

## ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
AAList = []

print("\n********************All the amino acids of the Primary Strand************************\n")

for RFNumber in range(0, 3):
    AASequence_1 = Translate(DnaSeq, RFNumber)
    print("\nthe amino acid seqeunce of RF {:d} is: \n".format(RFNumber+1))
    print(AASequence_1)

    AAlist.append(AASequence_1)

stop = input("\n Press return to finish........")
```

## -------------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
main()
```

The code runs good, we get the prompt to enter the file name but line 43 throws up an index out of range error. If there is any simple mistake there, any help would be greatly appreciated. I hope my question makes sense.

This is a small sample of the text file. It is the genetic sequence of the novel corona virus SARS_COV_2.txt

```
MN908947.3 Severe acute respiratory syndrome coronavirus 2 isolate Wuhan-Hu-1, complete genome
ATTAAAGGTTTATACCTTCCCAGGTAACAAACCAACCAACTTTCGATCTCTTGTAGATCTGTTCTCTAAA
CGAACTTTAAAATCTGTGTGGCTGTCACTCGGCTGCATGCTTAGTGCACTCACGCAGTATAATTAATAAC
TAATTACTGTCGTTGACAGGACACGAGTAACTCGTCTATCTTCTGCAGGCTGCTTACGGTTTCGTCCGTG
TTGCAGCCGATCATCAGCACATCTAGGTTTCGTCCGGGTGTGACCGAAAGGTAAGATGGAGAGCCTTGTC
CCTGGTTTCAACGAGAAAACACACGTCCAACTCAGTTTGCCTGTTTTACAGGTTCGCGACGTGCTCGTAC
GTGGCTTTGGAGACTCCGTGGAGGAGGTCTTATCAGAGGCACGTCAACATCTTAAAGATGGCACTTGTGG
CTTAGTAGAAGTTGAAAAAGGCGTTTTGCCTCAACTTGAACAGCCCTATGTGTTCATCAAACGTTCGGAT
GCTCGAACTGCACCTCATGGTCATGTTATGGTTGAGCTGGTAGCAGAACTCGAAGGCATTCAGTACGGTC
GTAGTGGTGAGACACTTGGTGTCCTTGTCCCTCATGTGGGCGAAATACCAGTGGCTTACCGCAAGGTTCT
TCTTCGTAAGAACGGTAATAAAGGAGCTGGTGGCCATAGTTACGGCGCCGATCTAAAGTCATTTGACTTA
GGCGACGAGCTTGGCACTGATCCTTATGAAGATTTTCAAGAAAACTGGAACACTAAACATAGCAGTGGTG
TTACCCGTGAACTCATGCGTGAGCTTAACGGAGGGGCATACACTCGCTATGTCGATAACAACTTCTGTGG
CCCTGATGGCTACCCTCTTGAGTGCATTAAAGACCTTCTAGCACGTGCTGGTAAAGCTTCATGCACTTTG
TCCGAACAACTGGACTTTATTGACACTAAGAGGGGTGTATACTGCTGCCGTGAACATGAGCATGAAATTG
CTTGGTACACGGAACGTTCTGAAAAGAGCTATGAATTGCAGACACCTTTTGAAATTAAATTGGCAAAGAA
ATTTGACACCTTCAATGGGGAATGTCCAAATTTTGTATTTCCCTTAAATTCCATAATCAAGACTATTCAA
CCAAGGGTTGAAAAGAAAAAGCTTGATGGCTTTATGGGTAGAATTCGATCTGTCTATCCAGTTGCGTCAC
CAAATGAATGCAACCAAATGTGCCTTTCAACTCTCATGAAGTGTGATCATTGTGGTGAAACTTCATGGCA
GACGGGCGATTTTGTTAAAGCCACTTGCGAATTTTGTGGCACTGAGAATTTGACTAAAGAAGGTGCCACT
ACTTGTGGTTACTTACCCCAAAATGCTGTTGTTAAAATTTATTGTCCAGCATGTCACAATTCAGAAGTAG
GACCTGAGCATAGTCTTGCCGAATACCATAATGAATCTGGCTTGAAAACCATTCTTCGTAAGGGTGGTCG
CACTATTGCCTTTGGAGGCTGTGTGTTCTCTTATGTTGGTTGCCATAACAAGTGTGCCTATTGGGTTCCA
CGTGCTAGCGCTAACATAGGTTGTAACCATACAGGTGTTGTTGGAGAAGGTTCCGAAGGTCTTAATGACA
ACCTTCTTGAAATACTCCAAAAAGAGAAAGTCAACATCAATATTGTTGGTGACTTTAAACTTAATGAAGA
GATCGCCATTATTTTGGCATCTTTTTCTGCTTCCACAAGTGCTTTTGTGGAAACTGTGAAAGGTTTGGAT
TATAAAGCATTCAAACAAATTGTTGAATCCTGTGGTAATTTTAAAGTTACAAAAGGAAAAGCTAAAAAAG
GTGCCTGGAATATTGGTGAACAGAAATCAATACTGAGTCCTCTTTATGCATTTGCATCAGAGGCTGCTCG
TGTTGTACGATCAATTTTCTCCCGCACTCTTGAAACTGCTCAAAATTCTGTGCGTGTTTTACAGAAGGCC
GCTATAACAATACTAGATGGAATTTCACAGTATTCACTGAGACTCATTGATGCTATGATGTTCACATCTG
ATTTGGCTACTAACAATCTAGTTGTAATGGCCTACATTACAGGTGGTGTTGTTCAGTTGACTTCGCAGTG
GCTAACTAACATCTTTGGCACTGTTTATGAAAAACTCAAACCCGTCCTTGATTGGCTTGAAGAGAAGTTT
AAGGAAGGTGTAGAGTTTCTTAGAGACGGTTGGGAAATTGTTAAATTTATCTCAACCTGTGCTTGTGAAA
TTGTCGGTGGACAAATTGTCACCTGTGCAAAGGAAATTAAGGAGAGTGTTCAGACATTCTTTAAGCTTGT
AAATAAATTTTTGGCTTTGTGTGCTGACTCTATCATTATTGGTGGAGCTAAACTTAAAGCCTTGAATTTA
GGTGAAACATTTGTCACGCACTCAAAGGGATTGTACAGAAAGTGTGTTAAATCCAGAGAAGAAACTGGCC
TACTCATGCCTCTAAAAGCCCCAAAAGAAATTATCTTCTTAGAGGGAGAAACACTTCCCACAGAAGTGTT
AACAGAGGAAGTTGTCTTGAAAACTGGTGATTTACAACCATTAGAACAACCTACTAGTGAAGCTGTTGAA
```

Comment: hmmm, that's a **lot** of Python code to read a file.  what's the nature of the desired result instead?  would also help if you copied us the exact error message, along with what's in *line 43*.

Comment: The exact question is. Implement code to find Open Reading Frames in a DNA sequence of the sars virus. Sample code provided. After determining the Amino acid sequence of a DNA strand.

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys. I am really sorry and appreciate the help. I just figured there is tables and data missing from the code hence not making any sense. Closed for now. Happy coding.